# Only able to retrieve 1 record using a while loop when I know there is actually 2?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I currently have a simple query to the database which should retrieve 2 different items from my database. I know that it's finding the database and retrieving but it seems to only retrieve 1 record.

My Question is: Why is the code below not pulling anymore than 1 record from the database?

```
<?php

include('config.php');

$sql = "SELECT * FROM sponsoredBackground ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3";
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $con ); 
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not get data: ' . mysql_error());
}

echo "<div id=\"headerSlider\">";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($retval))
{

?>
<div class="headerContainer" style="background: transparent url('/images/<?php echo $row['imageName']; ?>') 0 0 no-repeat;">
        <div class="headerLeftContent">
            <div class="sponsoredBackground">
                <a href="http://<?php echo $row['url']; ?>">        
                    View this Opportunity
                </a>
            </div>
            <p style="font-size:18px; color:white;">Search by Location:</p>
                <select id="location" name="location" class="selectDropDown">
                    <option>Select Location...</option>
                    <option value="AcrossScotland">Across Scotland</option>
                    <option value="Aberdeen">Aberdeen</option>
                    <option value="Aberdeenshire">Aberdeenshire</option>
                    <option value="Angus">Angus</option>
                    <option value="Argyll/Bute">Argyll And Bute</option>
                    <option value="Clackmannanshire">Clackmannanshire</option>
                    <option value="Dumfries/Galloway">Dumfries And Galloway</option>
                    <option value="Dundee">Dundee</option>
                    <option value="EastAyrshire">East Ayrshire</option>
                    <option value="EastDunbartonshire">East Dunbartonshire</option>
                    <option value="EastLothian">East Lothian</option>
                    <option value="EastRenfrewshire">East Renfrewshire</option>
                    <option value="Edinburgh">Edinburgh</option>
                    <option value="EileanSiar">Eilean Siar</option>
                    <option value="Falkirk">Falkirk</option>
                    <option value="Fife">Fife</option>
                    <option value="Glasgow">Glasgow</option>
                    <option value="Highlands">Highlands</option>
                    <option value="Inverclyde">Inverclyde</option>
                    <option value="Midlothian">Midlothian</option>
                    <option value="Moray">Moray</option>
                    <option value="NorthAyrshire">North Ayrshire</option>
                    <option value="NorthLanarkshire">North Lanarkshire</option>
                    <option value="Orkney">Orkney</option>
                    <option value="Perth/Kinross">Perth And Kinross</option>
                    <option value="Renfrewshire">Renfrewshire</option>
                    <option value="ScottishBorders">Scottish Borders</option>
                    <option value="ShetlandIslands">Shetland Islands</option>
                    <option value="SouthAyrshire">South Ayrshire</option>
                    <option value="SouthLanarkshire">South Lanarkshire</option>
                    <option value="Stirling">Stirling</option>
                    <option value="WestDunbartonshire">West Dunbartonshire</option>
                    <option value="WestLothian">West Lothian</option>
            </select>
            <p style="font-size:18px; color:white;">Search by Category:</p>
            <select id="category" name="category" class="selectDropDown">
                    <option>Select Category...</option>
                    <option value="AllCategories">All Categories</option>
                    <option value="Financial">Financial</option>
                    <option value="Administration">Business And Administration</option>
                    <option value="Care">Care</option>
                    <option value="Construction">Construction</option>
                    <option value="Creative">Creative</option>
                    <option value="Energy">Energy</option>
                    <option value="Engineering">Engineering</option>
                    <option value="Food/Drink">Food And Drink</option>
                    <option value="Hair/Beauty">Hair And Beauty</option>
                    <option value="Hospitality">Hospitality</option>
                    <option value="IT">IT</option>
                    <option value="Landbased">Landbased</option>
                    <option value="Mechanics/Transport">Motor And Transport</option>
                    <option value="Retail">Retail</option>
                    <option value="Scientific">Scientific</option>
                    <option value="Sport/Leisure">Sport And Leisure</option>
            </select>
            <p style="font-size:18px; color:white;">Search by Type:</p>
            <select id="type" class="selectDropDown">
                    <option>Select Type...</option>
                    <option value="AllTypes">All Types</option>
                    <option value="Apprenticeships">Apprenticeships</option>
                    <option value="Enterprise">Enterprise</option>
                    <option value="College">College</option>
                    <option value="University">University</option>
                    <option value="WorkExperience">Work Experience</option>
                    <option value="Voluntary">Voluntary</option>
                    <option value="Graduate">Graduate</option>
            </select>
        </div>  
        <div class="headerCenterContent">   
        </div>
        <div class="headerRightContent">
            <?php include('featuredEvents.php'); ?>
        </div>      
 </div>

<?php    
} 

echo "</div>";
echo "</div>";

echo "</body>";
echo "</html>";

?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried to run the sql statement (`SELECT * FROM sponsoredBackground ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3`) directly from your database management software/area (e.g. phpmyadmin) ?

Comment: Can you remove all but a simple echo in your loop to help narrow it down?

Comment: @kpsuperplane yeah I just tried it there and it returns the 2 records. Any suggestions?

Comment: @SomeSillyName I don't quite follow, could you be more clear?

Comment: If it works when you have removed everything but an echo, start adding code back in the file until it fails, and you'll know what the problem is.

Comment: Try to first extract data into a array. Then iterate array for your HTML code. In this case, you can better debug the problem. It also remove chances for accidentally mysql_fetch inside loop.

Comment: If the result displayed is the second item, then you are displaying the result over and above the first one..

Answer (score 0):

It most likely that `featuredEvents.php` that you include on the page does some sql stuff as well just double check and sure that it doesnt have a variable `$retval`.